# Converting existing android support to androidX

Tags: java, android, androidx

I am working on an existing project. I want to convert my android project(oreo) from the support library to androidX library. I have tried many tricks and tips but no progress at all.

What is the easiest approach to do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

Comment: This article contains a step by step guide for AndroidX migration and the issues you face. https://handyopinion.com/ultimate-guide-to-migrate-android-project-to-androidx/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Update your android studio

  https://developer.android.com/studio
- Set compileSdkVersion to 28

  [image]
- Set com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 in build.grade(project:X) in
  dependencies to min 3.2

  [image]
- Go to Refactor-> Migrate to androidX

  [image]

Comment: Although this answer is correct. But only in simple projects it works. In complex projects, we need to fix some errors manually. The following article will help you.
https://handyopinion.com/ultimate-guide-to-migrate-android-project-to-androidx/

Answer (score 9):

**Try this**

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

For [Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. You have to click on the **Refactor** menu option and then click **Migrate to AndroidX** option.

This article gives step by step procedure to [Migrate your project to AndroidX](https://www.gsrikar.com/2019/01/migrate-to-androidx.html) packages.

*Disclaimer:* I'm the author of the blog.