# Unable to support toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-toolbar, androidx

I am unable to get support V-7 or toolbar in Java Class

```
package com.adworld.admin.ab;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question a bit to format the code. You should do that yourself next time. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and clarify what the problem is. What do you mean by "unable t get support"? What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: convert your project to androidx follow  [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428961) steps

Answer (score 0):

You are using AndroidX so the package you need to import is -

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```