# Unable to use android.arch.lifecycle:extensions and com.android.support:preference

Tags: android, gradle

I need to use `LifecycleObserver` in my app (already existing one).

This's my `build.gradle` (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.tux.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Of course I put also:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

in project `build.gradle`.

After gradle sync I got an error about incompatibility between `com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1` and `androidx.*` dependencies.
If I try to compile things get worse. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have mixed up both support library and androidX.

Migrate everything to androidX. Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) official guide

**1.** With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

**2.** In your gradle.properties file, add these lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428961/7360848) answer for details.

Comment: I got it. But I was wondering if `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` was AndroidX or not.. it seems that there's a more specific package for AndroidX ...

Comment: @weirdgyn no, it is not in androidX. most probably any library you added has adapted to androidX, and that is causing the issue