# Can I have in the same gradle project an Andoid app and some Java11/FX modules with a shared module?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, openjfx

I'm building a project in Kotlin actually there are these modules:

- cli (kotlin / Java 11)
- gui (kotlin / Java 11 + TornadoFX / OpenJFX)
- shared (pure kotlin)

Now I want to make an Android app that uses the shared module, but form IntelliJ I get this error during the creation of that Android module:

"project needs to be converted to androidx.* dependencies"

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428697/converting-existing-android-support-to-androidx ?

Comment: yes I have already checked that thread but there is no solution, actually I have made by hand the app module :-(